# webapi c# puzzling load test results with async await

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

We are doing a load test on one of our web api end point and we can't believe the results that we are seeing.

In scenario 1 our tps (throughput per second) is ~1/sec while in scenario 2 our tps is ~3/sec. We expected a higher tps in scenario 1 than in 2.

Scenario 1 is our current system where we call service 1. Scenario 2 is the new system where we are introducing a bridge service in the middle to combine results from service 1 and service 2. Hence, scenario 2 should have lower throughput than scenario 1, because in scenario 1 we are directly calling our service 1.

All the services are in web api asp.net 4.5. Service 1 and 2 does not have async await operations. Bridge Service has async await operations and makes call to service 1 and 2 at the same time and waits for both the calls to finish. Call to service 1 always take longer than call to service 2. Hence, service 1 decides the total call time. The server is windows server 2012 R2 and IIS 8. Bridge service and Service 1 are deployed on the same server and are in the same application pool. Service 2 is deployed on another server.

Also, we verified that we are making the exact same call to Service 1 in both the scenarios.

We are seeing the same results in JMeter and soap ui.

[image]

Following is the code from bridge service:
[image]

Comment: In the 2 scenarios, what is shared? Is the code deployment identical? Are both instances of S1 the exact same IIS site and endpoint on the same physical server? Right now I can only think of very unlikely explanations.

Comment: Can you post the bridge code?

Comment: Hope my joke is welcome here! Show us some code, we can only guess right now...

Comment: @usr Service 1 is the same service in both the scenarios. It's just that we are directly calling service 1 in scenario 1 and indirectly calling in scenario 2.

Comment: @usr I have included the bridge service code in the question

Comment: ***Just as a note***: Diagram screenshots are fine, but you should avoid posting code as screenshot always, if at all possible. Some people will either use your code as an example to answer your question and having it as text in your question, allows them to easily copy+paste and do required changes to illustrate what you have to do, when/if necessary.

Comment: Can you add timing code to service 1 so that it self-reports how long it took? That way we can check if the service actually got faster somehow or if it's something else. If it didn't get faster the problem is in the caller.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your valuable feedback! We found the issue to be asp.net session level locking

Answer (score 1):

Apparently our call to service 1 wasn't same in both the scenarios. When we call service 1 directly we pass the ASP.NetSessionId in the cookie, but when the bridge called the service 1 it didn't pass the session id in the cookie.

Verdict:
In our original load test we used one ASP.NetSessionId and asp.net has some session level locks, hence it reduced the performance.

Hence, to test the session level lock theory, we did a load test by simulating 50 users instead of 1 user, and this time the performance is on par with bridge.